# Switch bean by changing properties in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have one interface MyInterface, and 2 implementation beans: FirstImpl & SeconImpl. I want to switch between using these 2 implementations while program is running without restarting it, by only changing a property in application.properties file, e.g: interface.bean.default=FirstImpl change to interface.bean.default=SecondImpl.
Anyone knows how to do that with Spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `@ConditionalOnProperty`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyInterfaceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my.interfacte.impl", havingValue="firstImpl")
    public MyInterface firstImpl(){
        return new FirstImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my.interfacte.impl", havingValue="secondImpl")
    public MyInterface secondImpl(){
        return new SecondImpl();
    }
}
```

and when you update your property in `application.properties` with actuator/refresh to:

```
my.interfacte.impl=firstImpl
```

you will have your `FirstImpl` instance. When you have:

```
my.interfacte.impl=secondImpl
```

you will have your `SecondImpl`.

Comment: Hi Hasan, it only works if I restart application after changing profile. My purpose is not to do application restart, only need to call /actuator/refresh after changing config and everything is effective!

Comment: @nguyenbkcse I see. Updated the answer. Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Hasan, your update only works if I customize it a little bit as below:

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class MyInterfaceConfiguration {

    @Value("${my.interfacte.impl}")
    String impl;

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public MyInterface getBean(){
        if ("firstImpl".equals(impl)) {
            return new FirstImpl();
        } else if ("secondImpl".equals(impl)) {
            return new SecondImpl();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have to use 2 @RefreshScope at class level and bean creation method level!